# Slackbot written in Swift 4 deployed on Heroku

Tags: swift, heroku, slack, swift4, heroku-api

I wrote a Slackbot with `SlackKit` and Swift `4.0`. I followed a very simple and easy to understand tutorial from [Peter Zignego](https://medium.com/@pvzig/building-slack-bots-in-swift-b99e243e444c)

He deployed his Bot at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)

So first issue that appears was that I use a array extension which gives me a random item from a given collection:

```
extension Array {
    /// Picks `n` random elements (partial Fisher-Yates shuffle approach)
    subscript (randomPick n: Int) -> [Element] {
      var copy = self
      for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: count - n - 1, by: -1) {
          copy.swapAt(i, Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i + 1))))
      }
      return Array(copy.suffix(n))
    }
}
```

With this code I´ve got no build issues and I want to push my code to `Heroku` but while it runs throw the deployment an error occurs:

`error: use of unresolved identifier 'arc4random_uniform'`

After searching I found a Swift reported [Bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-685) and changed my code to:

```
extension Array {
    /// Picks `n` random elements (partial Fisher-Yates shuffle approach)
    subscript (randomPick n: Int) -> [Element] {
        var copy = self
        for i in stride(from: count - 1, to: count - n - 1, by: -1) {
            #if os(Linux)
                copy.swapAt(i, Int(random() % (i + 1)))
            #else
                copy.swapAt(i, Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i + 1))))
            #endif

         }
         return Array(copy.suffix(n))
    }
}
```

Now my code pushed and deployed on `Heroku` successfully.

But when I want to start the Bot in my `Slack` Channel like:

```
rf24-dev-mac-1:support-dialer konstantin$ heroku run:detached slackbot
Running slackbot on ⬢ support-dialer... done, run.1246 (Free)
Run heroku logs --app support-dialer --dyno run.1246 to view the output.
```

and run the output command I get this:

```
2017-09-25T13:37:27.762135+00:00 heroku[run.1246]: Starting process with command `.build/release/support-dialer`
2017-09-25T13:37:28.335452+00:00 heroku[run.1246]: State changed from starting to up
2017-09-25T13:37:29.842073+00:00 heroku[run.1246]: Process exited with status 127
2017-09-25T13:37:29.779834+00:00 app[run.1246]: .build/release/support-dialer: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2017-09-25T13:37:29.856440+00:00 heroku[run.1246]: State changed from up to complete
```

So I have no idea what I can do to fix this because it does not start the Slackbot and when I clicked the [deploy link](https://support-dialer.herokuapp.com/) at `Heroku` it also says there is an error.